# Problems using subl command in terminal: "Command not found" & "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, terminal, sublimetext2

I want to apologize in advance that this is a newbie question! I've spent the last 2 hours trying to find a solution.

I have two problems (I'm sure related).

**Background:**

This is what my $PATH looks like:

/Users/Sponsi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/Sponsi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/Sponsi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/Sponsi/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin

**Problem #1**

I am trying to use the command-line command "subl" to launch Sublime Text 2 on OSX.

I entered the following command:
"`ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl`

It only halfway worked - when I enter "subl" I get "Command not found". But when I re-enter the command above it says "Already exists."

I searched online and found a (somewhat) fix. I added the following to my .bashrc:

```
echo 'export PATH="./bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc 
source ~/.bashrc
```

Using the command "subl" does work but only temporarily. If I exit terminal or switch to another directory it stops working (bringing me into problem #2, see below.)

**Problem # 2:**

When I try to pull up a file under another directory using the command "subl" I get "-bash: ./bin/subl: No such file or directory" I confirmed the file I want to edit does exist.

BTW, I am following the Ruby tutorial found @ http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Run each command in the Terminal (in this order):

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/subl
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin
$ subl .
```

This should work!

**Note:** First you should check that your sublime's app is in Applications folder and it's name is Sublime Text 2, if not, you should change the name in the second command and type the name of sublime's app.

Comment: only thing that seemed to work for me for some reason.

Comment: Note added above helped me.

Comment: amazing, work on me

192:~ radityagumay$ cd
192:~ radityagumay$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/subl
192:~ radityagumay$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin
192:~ radityagumay$ subl .

Answer (score 94):

if you are using RVM, do this:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/.rvm/bin/subl
```

Comment: Works perfectly, must be something with rvm messing with the path.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you, Bob.

Answer (score 34):

**For El Captain or later OS:**

In **El Capitan**, you are not allowed to write to /usr/bin, but writing to /usr/local/bin is ok. By default, /usr/local/bin should also be in your path variable.

For **Sublime Text 3**

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/subl
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

For **Sublime Text 2**

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/subl
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Comment: I've had trouble with this all day, this was the only thing thats worked. thank you!

Answer (score 25):

I stuck mine in /usr/bin

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin`

or for Sublime 3 or later

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin`

It's already in $PATH

Comment: This is the best way to go if you have /usr/bin already. Picks it up automatically without any other fidgeting.

Comment: For Sublime Text 3 (and later) just leave off the "\ 2". Like this: `sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin`

Comment: I get operation not permitted when I do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Could be a permissions thing or a corrupt file. Hard to know.

Comment: [Per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36734569/1608016), it has to do with El Capitan's new System Integrity Protection feature. I was running into the same issue, and changing the location of the link to `/usr/local/bin` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using **Sublime Text 3** you need to adjust the commands in isanjosgon's answer:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/subl
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/
$ subl .
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, on a new Mac recently configured. I had RVM installed before oh-my-zsh and sublime text and I was running into the same problems. I tried different locations on the path

```
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
```

all of them in the path. What worked for me was to get rid of the quotes on the command line running as

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin/subl
```

Comment: This is what fixed it for me too.

Comment: The Sublime Text documentation https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html has quotes around the /Applications.... path. You are quite right that leaving the quotes off is the solution. To see your path type 'echo $PATH'. /usr/local/bin is the best place to put the symlink and should already be in your path.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ alias subl="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
```

`$ subl .`
This works! :D

Answer (score 3):

You can also create new alias if you want like

> alias subl="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `~/.bashrc` file to contain this line at the end of it:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Notice the `~` is there instead  of the `.` from your example? The `~` signifies your home directory, which is where your `.bashrc` file lives. The dot signifies the *current* directory of your terminal window.

Once you've made the change, close your terminal window and re-open it. Then `subl` should be avaiable on the PATH.

Comment: I'm confused. Now, all I'm receiving is "Command not found". I've restarted my computer, reinstalled Sublime Text, deleted and re-added the subl file in my /bin, and reentered all the commands above to no avail. The only change I did to my computer was delete a user account - that shouldn't have anything to do with subl not working, right?

Comment: Perhaps use `export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH` instead? I probably should have said that in the first place. You shouldn't have to delete your program and re-install it. This is purely a configuration issue external from the program itself.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first problem, could it be that you don't have a bin directory set up under you home directory (i.e., ~/bin)? To check this, type the following:

```
cd ~/
ls -l
```

If there is no bin directory, type the following:

```
mkdir bin
```

Once you've created the directory, retype the following:

```
subl --help
```

Hopefully that takes care of the issue

Answer (score 1):

There's a slight change to the path from that in the accepted answer following an update to Sublime Text.

`ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/.rvm/bin/subl`

Answer (score 0):

The reason that when you changed directory or re-opened terminal then the PATH wouldn't work is that .bashrc is a non-login interactive file.

Simply use this line in terminal:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

will probably solve the problem since .bash_profile is loaded every time there is a login.

if you don't have .bash_profile,
just before using the above command, type this in Terminal:

```
cd ~
touch .bash_profile
```

then use the formal command.

I would not touch usr/local/bin usually since it is a system level folder. Heard that recently in OS X El Capitan, Apple made some permission restrictions.
So just put the clone in your home directory under /bin folder and adding the PATH in your .bash_profile, everything should then be working.

Answer (score 0):

In linux sublime 3, in your terminal paste

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin
```

Then

```
subl3 [filename]
```

Answer (score 0):

I first checked the `which subl`
returned nothing.
That meant have to add path of subl to PATH variable required.

So adding to PATH variable path of subl helped

```
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/
```

You may first want to find correct path of your subl and add that to PATH variable

If that works, add the path permanently by adding below command to your .bash_profle

export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/

Note: path to subl may differ in your system.