# Cannot create a symlink inside of /usr/bin even as sudo

Tags: macos, symlink, ln

When I try to symlink a binary in my /usr/bin folder, I get an Operation not permitted error:

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2
ln: /usr/bin/python2: Operation not permitted
```

Even as sudo, I get this error.

Comment: What's your 1.OS 2.Distribution 3. File system please?

Comment: Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.4

Comment: Have you tried the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled ?

Comment: create instead in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/sbin`

Comment: An alias will work a lot better - symlinking can cause a prompt to re-download xcode command line tools.

Answer (score 283):

### Why can't I symlink into `/usr/bin`?

El Capitan's new [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) feature prevents changes to several core parts of OS X, including most of `/usr/`, even by root.

### How can I still add executable files to my path?

Local customizations, such as what you're doing, belong in `/usr/local` instead. The path `/usr/local/bin` doesn't exist by default, but you can create it and put custom binaries (and symlinks) in it:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python2
```

Note that while `/usr/local/bin` doesn't exist by default, it *is* in the default PATH, so as soon as you create it, it'll be searched for commands.

#### Disabling SIP

It's also possible to disable System Integrity Protection, but it's generally best to leave it on and do customization in more appropriate locations. An Apple Stack Exchange question has more details on this: [What is the Rootless Feature in El-Captain, really?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really).

Comment: If I do this and run `python` it calls the file under `/usr/bin/python` instead of the file `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: @DanielW. What is your `PATH` set to? Normally, `/usr/local/bin` will be listed before `/usr/bin`, so it'll take precedence.

Comment: I had to restart and mangle with `brew link` then it worked tbh but you are very right with the `PATH` setting.

Comment: Strange.  I have /usr/local/bin prior to /usr/bin in my PATH setting.  /usr/bin/python points to v2.7 and /usr/local/bin/python points to v3.9.  When I run the command "python --version" it returns "Version 2.7".  Precedence... what precedence?

Comment: @muztheaxe Do you have a function or alias overriding `python`? If you're using bash, run `type python` (or `type -a python` for a full list of possible meanings); if you're using zsh, run `whence python` (or `whence -a python`).

Comment: The path was originally set to this: export PATH=/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH
I removed this first directory and then it worked.  Made me thing that perhaps something in "php@7.3" may have been a problem.  I am lazy and didn't investigate any further.

Comment: +1 to not disabling System Integrity Protection, but symlinking it under /usr/local/bin no longer works, and instead prompts a re-download of xcode command line tools.

Answer (score 29):

I created the symbolic link for Sublime Text 3 in Mac OS High Sierra as

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/
```

I was also trying to create the symbolic link in "/usr/bin" and was getting Operation Not Permitted.

Then I created the symbolic link in "/usr/local/bin" and there was not error. The symbolic link works fine. Just ensure that "/usr/local/bin" is in the path.

So, it seems the access to "/usr/bin" is restricted.

Answer (score 11):

Restart the system -> long press **cmd + R**. 
select a terminal from utilities menu
type the following command **csrutil disable**
close terminal and restart system.

Comment: This disables System Integrity Protection. Probably best to find another, more secure solution instead.

Comment: Personally, I think this is the right solution. I see no reason for the OS to block me from symlinking things in this directory or any directory as `sudo`.

Comment: Maybe the full solution is to disable it, place the symlink and re-enable csrutil?

Comment: Macs with Apple Silicon need to shut down and be started with the power button held down until the boot options appear.

Answer (score 2):

```
  1. Create a symbolic link to psql in usr/bin (for mac only)
         command: sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/psql /usr/bin/psql
```

if you are not able to create symnbolic link due to permission issue, it will be due to "csrutil".after disabling csrutil you can create symbollic link.
Follow these steps to disable CSRUtill :

Restart your Mac.
Before OS X starts up, hold down Command-R and keep it held down until you see an Apple icon and a progress bar. Release. This boots you into Recovery.
From the Utilities(on the top bar)menu, select Terminal.
At the prompt type exactly the following and then press Return: csrutil disable
Terminal should display a message that SIP was disabled.
From the  menu, select Restart.

Answer (score -8):

Try running `sudo su` first then running the command w/ root level.

Comment: This will not resolve the OPs issue.  The problem has to do with the system integrity protection on modern MacOS systems.