# Install Python 3 to /usr/bin/ on macOS

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, path

I installed python2.x and python3.x using homebrew and the executable python paths are listed below:

```
$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
```

It's quite too long and not so clean to write a shebang in a python code to make it runnable on Terminal:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python OR
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
```

I prefer

```
#!/usr/bin/python OR
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

My issue here is, how can I correcly move or reinstall python on macOS to **/usr/bin** such as 
 `/usr/bin/python` OR `/usr/bin/python3` 
Instead of 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3`

Comment: Maybe just create a symbolic link to /bin

Comment: Instead of `#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3` try `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Answer (score 6):

This is NOT possible on Mac OS X El Capitan anymore as from then on System Integrity Protection prevents that. More info in [Cannot create a symlink inside of /usr/bin even as sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730549/cannot-create-a-symlink-inside-of-usr-bin-even-as-sudo)

Answer (score 3):

Create a symbolic link in `/usr/bin/`

Open terminal and do:

```
$ sudo ln /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /usr/bin/python
$ sudo ln /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3
```

You can now do what you wanted to do.

**Edit**: Unfortunately as you can read from the other answers, this solution no longer works on MacOS >= El Capitan due to System Integrity Protection. ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730549/cannot-create-a-symlink-inside-of-usr-bin-even-as-sudo))

A possible alternative is to use the folder `/usr/local/bin` that should be accessible.

Comment: $ sudo ln /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3
Password:
ln: /usr/bin/python3: Operation not permitted

Comment: @WINSergey as you can read from MDr answer my solution is no longer working on MacOS >= El Capitan.

Comment: Yes @luca-angioloni, in my case work: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7

Comment: @WINSergey I also updated my answer to address your problem.

Comment: Use: `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Answer (score 2):

The basic question in the OP seems to not be doable because the newer Mac OSes have "System Integrity Protection" which prevents "unauthorized" changes to key directories such as `/usr/bin`, and `sudo` cannot override that.

The suggestion of using `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/Frameworks` seems like it should work (I haven't tried it). However, at `https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac`, Matthew Broberg suggests that it is likely to create problems when updating.

In that same article, Moshe Zadka recommends using `pyenv` to manage Python environments and using shell aliases rather than symlinks.

I was going to go with the `/usr/local` suggestion above, but having found this contraindication, I'm going to try Moshe's method. I'll report back here if I hit any snags.

Update: I followed the method and I still was getting `pip` not found and `which python` and `python -V` were not giving me the expected results. Doh! I ran:

`. ~/.bash_profile`

(where I had put the recommended `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` command) and suddenly everything was finding the paths and versions as expected.