# bazel build tensorflow graph transform looking for /usr/bin/python3, but file does not exist (and I cannot create it)

Tags: macos, tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-lite

I am following https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md#optimizing-for-deployment and running this command:

`bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:transform_graph`

and getting this error:

> ERROR: /Users/daniel/software/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:2475:1: no such package '@local_config_git//': Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/Users/daniel/software/tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bzl", line 52
>           _fail(result.stderr)
>       File "/Users/daniel/software/tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bzl", line 14, in _fail
>           fail(("%sGit Configuration Error:%s %...)))
>   Git Configuration Error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/python3" (in directory "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_daniel/bff3ff07c5339b6b7496cc244d119e78/external/local_config_git"): error=2, No such file or directory
>    and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'
>   ERROR: /Users/daniel/software/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:2475:1: no such package '@local_config_git//': Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/Users/daniel/software/tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bzl", line 52
>           _fail(result.stderr)
>       File "/Users/daniel/software/tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bzl", line 14, in _fail
>           fail(("%sGit Configuration Error:%s %...)))
>   Git Configuration Error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/python3" (in directory "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_daniel/bff3ff07c5339b6b7496cc244d119e78/external/local_config_git"): error=2, No such file or directory
>    and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'
>   ERROR: /Users/daniel/software/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:2475:1: no such package '@local_config_git//': Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/Users/daniel/software/tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bzl", line 52
>           _fail(result.stderr)
>       File "/Users/daniel/software/tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bzl", line 14, in _fail
>           fail(("%sGit Configuration Error:%s %...)))
>   Git Configuration Error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/python3" (in directory "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_daniel/bff3ff07c5339b6b7496cc244d119e78/external/local_config_git"): error=2, No such file or directory
>    and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'
>   ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph' failed; build aborted: no such package '@local_config_git//': Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/Users/daniel/software/tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bzl", line 52
>           _fail(result.stderr)
>       File "/Users/daniel/software/tensorflow/third_party/git/git_configure.bzl", line 14, in _fail
>           fail(("%sGit Configuration Error:%s %...)))
>   Git Configuration Error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/python3" (in directory "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_daniel/bff3ff07c5339b6b7496cc244d119e78/external/local_config_git"): error=2, No such file or directory
>   ```

The recurring line of interest (I think) is `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/python3"`. The error message is correct:

`$ ls /usr/bin/python3
ls: /usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory`

But I'm not sure why it's looking for `/usr/bin/python3` in the first place, as it's not in my PATH:

`$ type python3
python3 is /anaconda3/bin/python3`

Is bazel hardcoded to look for that path? I can't create anything in `/usr/bin`, see: [Install Python 3 to /usr/bin/ on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928053/install-python-3-to-usr-bin-on-macos)

I don't really know what to do here. Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE] -- Running `./configure` from `tensorflow/` and accepting all the default options fixed my problem.

Comment: to add: it seems one has to use python3