# Cannot run symlink command - operation not permitted

Tags: macos, symlink, ln

I have this command:

```
$ sudo ln -s  "$(which chromedriver)" /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

and I get this error

```
ln: /usr/bin/google-chrome: Operation not permitted
```

I tried with/without sudo, same thing. Anyone know what's up?

Comment: btw, `$(which chromedriver)` yields -> `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

Comment: It looks like `/usr/bin/google-chrome` already exists. Is that true? You'll need to add the `-f` flag to `ln` to overwrite the existing file (if that's what you want).

Comment: Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730549/cannot-create-a-symlink-inside-of-usr-bin-even-as-sudo#36734569](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730549/cannot-create-a-symlink-inside-of-usr-bin-even-as-sudo#36734569). /usr/local/bin is the right place for things like this, so just leave it there.